# Spliting single array into arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as defined,

```
Array(
    [0] => TEST 
    [1] => 1 
    [2] => 2 
    [3] => 3 
)
```

Now I need to convert the array into three sub different arrays based on above array

Required Format:

```
Array (
    [NAME] => Test
    [VALUE] => 1
)
Array (
    [NAME] => Test
    [VALUE] => 2
)
Array (
    [NAME] => Test
    [VALUE] => 3
)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @u_mulder I have tried using for and foreach but the output was not as expected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_shift` to get first element:

```
$name = array_shift($arr);
$res = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $res[] = ["NAME" => $name, "VALUE" => $value];
}
print_r($res);
```

[array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) — Shift an element off the beginning of array

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/JVqHf)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => TEST 
            [VALUE] => 1 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => TEST 
            [VALUE] => 2 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => TEST 
            [VALUE] => 3 
        )

)
```

**EDIT**

If you want three individual sub arrays then use [extract](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php),

```
$temp = array_shift($arr);
$res  = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $res['arr'.$key] = ["NAME" => $temp, "VALUE" => $value];
}
extract($res);
print_r($arr0);
print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
```

extract — Import variables into the current symbol table from an array

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/XYLGI)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [NAME] => TEST 
    [VALUE] => 1 
)
Array
(
    [NAME] => TEST 
    [VALUE] => 2 
)
Array
(
    [NAME] => TEST 
    [VALUE] => 3 
)
```